# Weak Convergence of piecewise constant function (Evans PDE, Section 8.7, Q1b)

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

I'm having problems with the following question from Evans' PDE book (From Section 8.7, Question 1b);

> Fix $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $0<\lambda <1$. Define $$u_k(x)= \begin{cases} a &\text{if} & j/k\leq x < (j+\lambda)/k \\
> b &\text{if} & (j+\lambda)\leq x<(j+1)/k\end{cases} (j=0,\ldots,k-1)$$
>   Prove that $u_k$ converges to $\lambda a+ (1-\lambda)b$ weakly in $L^2(0,1)$.

Firstly I observed it reduces to the case $a=1,b=0$ by linearity. But now I just can't find any way to compare $\lambda\int g(x)\,dx$ and $\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \int_{j/k}^{(j+\lambda)/k}g(x)\, dx$ (their difference converging to zero is what I need) - I've tried many things including integration by parts and changes of variables (clearly it's alright to just show it for smooth functions then use a density argument) but nothing seems to help.

Anyone got any good hints?

Comment: Note that weak convergence means here that $\int u_k \varphi\to \int u \varphi$ for any $\varphi\in L^2(0,1)$. The functions $C_c^\infty(0,1)$ are dense in $L^2(0,1)$. Hence, it might be a good idea to consider such functions smooth and compactly supported functions. Can you show the convergence of the integrals against $\int u\varphi =\int (\lambda a +(1-\lambda) b) \varphi$? then by the fundamental theorem of calculus of variations $u$ is the distributional limit, and by density it should also be the $L^2$ weak limit. Have you tried something like that?

Comment: Additional things to think of: I think one could also try to choose $\varphi$ as characteristic functions of intervals in $(0,1)$.

Comment: Done it now - turns out that it's fairly simple for a characteristic function to just write the functional $u_k$ evaluated at it as a sum of a few things evaluated at integer parts.

Comment: Forgot to say - thanks for the hint! 

Some detail on how to finish for anyone reading - in essence, the number of intervals $[j/k, (j+\lambda)/k]$ which are fully contained in a given interval $[a,b]$ is $[bk - \lambda] - [ak] -1$ (which behaves like $bk - ak$ in limit) as the first value of $j$ has $(j-1)/k < a \leq j/k$ and the last one has $(j+\lambda)/k \leq b < (j+1+\lambda)/k$. Then anything left over has length at most $2 \lambda /k$. So then as the intervals have length $\lambda /k$ each, this gives the result for characteristic functions, then it follows by density/linearity etc.

Comment: For completeness, let me add the following. The reason my first comment uses compactly supported functions had the intention to show distributional convergence. From there on weak convergence is often easier to show. Since $u_k$ is bounded a weakly convergent subsequence exists. Then, one only needs to identify the two limits and to get back to the full sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints.

We first observe that it suffices to consider step functions, as they are dense in $L^2[0,1]$. In particular, step functions $f$ for which there is an $N\in\mathbb N$, such that 
$f$ restricted in $[(j-1)/N,j/N]$ is constant, for every $j=1,\ldots,N$.

Next, observe that, for every $j,N\in\mathbb N$, with $0<1\le N$,
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{(j-1)/N}^{j/N} u_k=\frac{\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b}{N}.
$$